# Создание визуальной среды MySQL

Tags: c#, c++, mysql

Идея такова:

Хочу создать визуальную среду для MySQL.

Что она будет делать или принцип работы:

Согласно действиям в среде, будет создаваться MySQL-код. Т.е, допустим пользователь нажал на значок "+". Тогда вырабатывается код: CREATE DATABASE что-то;

Этим я справлюсь. Главная проблема в следующем:

Как мне сделать, чтобы полученный код потом интерпретировать в MySQL отладчике и создать *.sql или* dba файл? Или я могу просто создать файл с таким расширением и не понадобится больше его интерпретировать???

Да и если я создал файл с таким расширением, то как выполнить его могу??? Могу как то связать свою программу и отладчик MySQL(командная строка, которая) чтобы после создания файла, внутри же программы выполнить его и создать БД?

Надеюсь смог как то довести свои мысли вам. Если нет, то спросите в комментах, я вам отвечу. Спасибо заранее!

P.S программу создам на C++ или же на C#.

Answer (score 3):

Вам необходимо:

1. Создать файл с расширением .sql и записать в него ваш исполняемый код.
2. Запустить выполнение sql-скрипта через отладчик MySQL, используя средства языка, например Process.Start() либо [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855224/how-to-execute-sql-mysql-file-in-my-c-sharp-application)

Comment: При этом сам MySQL отладчик должен иметься на компьютере пользователя. А что делать, как быть, если отладчик не установлен там. Как мне самому установить туда отладчик? А еще, нельзя как то объединить, связать, отладчик со своей программой. Как бы сделать одно целое?

Comment: Простите, я наверное спутал понятие отладчика MySQL и простой MySQL консоли. Я предполагал, что после того, как будет создан файл script.sql вы можете запустить его выполнение с помощью обычной MySQL консоли, через Process.Start() либо другими средствами языка.

Answer (score 2):

Скажите по секрету, чем вас не устраивают уже имеющиеся "визуальные среды" для работы с мусклом? 
Вот навскидку первый результат из гуглей: [Top 10 MySQL GUI Tools](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3880961/Top-10-MySQL-GUI-Tools.htm).

Comment: Тогда зачем мне учиться на программиста если все готовые уже есть???

Comment: ну просто некоторые части вопроса у вас такие, что, я думаю, вам прежде всего надо выучиться на пользователя гугл и на читателя документации прежде, чем на программиста.

я полагаю, что такого рода ресурсы (вроде этого или stackoverflow) предназначены всё-таки для решения неоднозначных сложных инженерных задач, а не для "мне лень читать маны, как мне сделать, чтобы было збс на таком-то яп"

Comment: Если не хочешь помогать зачем комментишь? От тебя ничего полезного сейчас

Comment: полезное - почитай, как работать с бд на том яп, на котором собрался писать

Comment: Я же ведь хочу чтобы тот самый MySQL работал внутри как бы оболочки программы. Я не нашел в гугле как соединить их вместе, чтобы он обрабатывал код внутри программы

Comment: ну вот вы не можете даже сформулировать мысль ясно
я думаю, что ознакомиться с литературой (не статьёй "делаем %something на %langname", а настоящей книгой) вам будет очень полезно как минимум для того, чтобы грамотно сформулировать вопрос, а в идеале - скорее всего, сможете самостоятельно найти решение

потому что при текущей постановке вопроса сложно понять, хотите ли вы, например, передавать по пайпу сгенерированные запросы в mysqlclient, или, например, хотите делать cursor execute

Comment: btw, на stackoverflow обычно такое закрывают как Not a real question: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: Что посоветуешь почитать? Напиши, я найду и прочту. Заранее спасибо